# How can I select the positive roots in a list calculated with NSolve?

Tags: list-manipulation

I've used `NSolve` to determine the roots of a nonlinear function. There are both positive and negative roots, and I only need the positive ones. I've tried using:

`Select[stuff, Positive]`

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? There are hundreds of items in the list so it's not something I can do by hand.

Comment: Avoid using `List` as a variable name: it's a reserved built-in. In general use lowercase variable names. Can you show a portion of your results?

Comment: @MarcoB The first item for example is:

```[{x->1.4}]```

Comment: Since the results of `NSolve` are lists of lists of rules, you should make sure that you apply the selector to the right portion, eg `Select[list, Positive[#[[1,2]]]&]`. But probably even better would be to add a constraint in `NSolve` to produce only the positive roots: `NSolve[{yourEquation, yourVariable > 0}, yourVariable]`, or use a domain specification like `PositiveReals` in NSolve (see docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sol = NSolve[{x^2 + y^3 == 1, 2 x + 3 y == 4}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

{{x -> 7.93641, y -> -3.95761}}

```
Cases[sol, (_ -> a_) /; a > 0, -1]
```

{x -> 7.93641}

Answer (score 1):

For @eldo's example:

```
sol = NSolve[{x^2 + y^3 == 1, 2 x + 3 y == 4}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 7.93641, y -> -3.95761}}

```
Select[First@sol, Positive@*Values]
```

> {x -> 7.93641}

---

```
Cases[sol, HoldPattern[a_ -> b_?Positive], {2}]
```

> {x -> 7.93641}